# Make NSNumberFormatter always treat rightmost two digits of input as fractional part

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, formatting, nsnumberformatter

I feel like the answer is right in front of my face but I cannot seem to find it.

My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    numFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    numFormatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    [numFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    [numFormatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];
    [numFormatter setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:YES];
    [numFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
}

-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField{

    inputLbl.text = [numFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[dummyTextField.text doubleValue]]];

}
```

If the user inputs 101, it displays as `$101.00` when I need `$1.01` so the input seems to start after the decimal point, when I want it start at the hundreds point of the decimals.

Comment: You mean you want to always treat the last two digits as the fractional part? What if the input is less than three digits?

Comment: Yes. If it was less than 3, say they input only "1", then I would want the result to be "0.01"

Comment: ...divide by 100 before formatting?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Ha......(facepalm) as I said, answer right in front of my face. If you want to submit that as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: We all have these moments...

Comment: WendiKidd has given a thorough and correct answer that encapsulates my proposed solution; there's no need for me to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSNumberFormater` takes in a *number* and formats *that number* according to whichever style you've set. If the user inputs 101, as you suggest, then one hundred and one is the number being formatted. You've selected the currency style, so you get `$101.00`. The number is still 101; it is just formatted to look like a currency amount.

If you want `$1.01`, you're going to have to input the number 1.01. The number formatter doesn't *change the number*. It just changes the way it's displayed. 1.01 is a number; `$1.01` is that number represented as currency. 1.01 is not equal to 101. The number formatter doesn't change the *number* you input, just how it's displayed.